# ffmpeg : mix audio and video of different length

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I have 2 files: 1 video file (without sound) -  length 6 seconds, 1 audio - length 10  seconds.
Both audio and video contains same conversation, but audio starts 4 seconds earlier and after that was started video.

```
[----------] audio
    [------] video
```

So, I want to mix them together to video file with length 10 seconds where first 4 seconds black screen with audio then goes real video and audio.

```
[====------] audio+video (where '=' is black screen)
```

I hope my description was clear enough ).
How can I do this with ffmpeg or gstreamer ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the video's resolution is WxH and framerate is F, and the difference in durations is D seconds, then the command is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -f lavfi -i color=s=WxH:r=F -filter_complex
          "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+D/TB[v];[2][v]overlay=eof_action=endall[vid]"
       -map "[vid]" -map 1:a output.mp4
```

Comment: But it requires to know prerequisites - Width x Height, Frame rate and Length difference in seconds (.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid it specification or somehow to calculate it automatically?