# ffmpeg - different video and audio length synchronization

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, flv

I have a task where the sound is longer and the image should come later.
Actually, this is exactly what I want, but it's a bit different: [ffmpeg : mix audio and video of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221165/ffmpeg-mix-audio-and-video-of-different-length)

First of all, I leave the picture I draw below to be understood.
[Click to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVyoF.png)

By doing this I am thinking of catching sync. With which ffmpeg command can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use offset.
I solved it this way. I will automatically add the corresponding time interval according to the difference between video and audio. I will use the programming language for this.

```
ffmpeg -i  finalsound.flv -itsoffset 00:00:44 -i finalvideo.flv -c copy final.flv
```

Thank you.